# SWRevealViewController - push next view controller storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a sidebar menu, made with SWRevealViewController.

I want to switch from the view controller and the view with the button to the next view controller. How I do that?
I try to used the ACTION SEGUE: "push", "modal", "revealview controller" and "revealview controller push controller".

But it doesn't works.

And I try it programmatically switch to the next viewcontroller.
MY CODE:

```
ViewController2 *vc2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];
[self.navigationcontroller pushViewController:vc2 animated:YES]
```

This change the ViewController, but without the view (blackscreen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems ViewController2 is a ViewController in storyboard. Try the below code:

```
ViewController2 * vc2 = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerId"];
```

You should give Storyboard ID for ViewController2 as ViewControllerId in your storyboard.

Please note that your current ViewController should be in a Navigationcontroller stack to call self.navigationcontroller.